# Microsoft Graph Missing Sites

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to fetch all the sites under our tenant and some are missings. We recently created a new site (not subsite) and we cannot found it when searching with Microsoft Graph.

Here's the request url that we are using:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/?search=*
```

I also tried to use this url from beta docs but it's not working either:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites?filter=root%20ne%20null&select=siteCollection,webUrl
```

Though, I can found it with the get by path url:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{hostname}:/{site-path}
```

Does the site need to have a specific setting to appear in the result when searching?

I want to be able to list all the sharepoint sites that exists.

Comment: What is the type of the new site? Or any other known config which different other sites?

Comment: It's a sharepoint site, not from team or group.

Comment: I assume it's a sharepoint site. Is there a way to know if it's a group, tream or sharepoint site?

Comment: The simplest way, try creating a few more common types of web sites and comparing them to the one you are now in case. I'm not sure if there's more simple way to do this, like PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my latest test, the following url not handle same data so different results(Attetion to my code comment):

```
//just return the team site(subsite of teams/sites)
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{hostname}:/{site-path}
//Will return the tenant site collection
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/root?select=siteCollection,webUrl&filter=root%20ne%20null
```

To get the modern team sites for the groups, we need to use groups end point from Microsoft Graph. No API to list all the modern team sites directly, we can loop through the groups and then get the site URL with this API: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<group-id>/drive/root/webUrl.`

Please check if the site in your case with issue is a modern team sites?

> Some reference from 3rd blog:
>
> https://www.eliostruyf.com/get-the-site-url-of-an-office-365-group-via-the-microsoft-graph/